# Displaying text randomly on banner

Tags: javascript

I am creating website that contains banner div at top and which has background image also now i have to put text on top of it like this

```
         welcome know my facilities
      1.xxxxxxxxxx          4.xxxxxxxxxxx
      2.xxxxxxxxxx          5.xxxxxxxxxxx
      3.xxxxxxxxxx          6.xxxxxxxxxx
```

how i display 1,2,3,4,5,6 randomly on banner using javascript.

Comment: Please provide some code snippets of what you have tried, so that other can easily understand the problem.

Comment: you haven't provided anything showing that you even tried something... give it a go using loads of documentation on the net and let us know if you're stuck...

Comment: What do you mean randomly? Do they have to be in a random order? Or is the text randomly selected from a set of say 20 options?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an array with an entry for each of the six options. Those will be entries `0` through `5` inclusive. Each entry has the HTML you want displayed for that entry.
2. Use `x = Math.floor(Math.random() * theArray.length);` to pick a random whole number between `0` and `5`, inclusive.
3. Use `theArray[x]` to retrieve the content you want to display.
4. Use `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector` to get a reference to the DOM element for the banner.
5. Use its `innerHTML` property to put the content in it.